# Upload file failed with 500 internal server error in rails

Tags: python, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here are logs from my server,

```
Started POST "/networktool/report/b842dc1f9652dbe" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-18 13:00:06 +0000
  Processing by NetworkToolController#report as */*
  Parameters: {"1.txt"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000adf7dc0 @original_filename="1.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"1.txt\"; filename=\"1.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140218-31778-nxbkfj>>, "house_secret"=>"b842dc1f9652dbe1"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:26:in `block in initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:28:in `block in initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:28:in `block in initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:28:in `block in initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:28:in `block in initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:103:in `accept'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:449:in `block in dump_ivars'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:447:in `dump_ivars'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:125:in `visit_Object'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:103:in `accept'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:293:in `block in visit_Hash'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:291:in `visit_Hash'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:103:in `accept'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:67:in `push'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:242:in `dump'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:38:in `quote'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:172:in `quote'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:10:in `block in to_sql'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:17:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_BindParam'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:119:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_Values'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:117:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Values'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:82:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:18:in `block in accept'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:16:in `accept'
  arel (2.2.3) lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:9:in `to_sql'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:91:in `insert'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/relation.rb:70:in `insert'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:313:in `create'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:51:in `create'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `block in create'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_create_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:294:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:408:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:194:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/base.rb:510:in `create'
   () usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/saw-d87445908ea8/lib/saw/controller.rb:40:in `saw'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20:in `track_changes'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:421:in `_run__153947068513133338__process_action__1911104675666003671__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:71:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:35:in `call'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
  rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:538:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.1.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
  railties (3.1.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.1.10) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.1.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.1.15) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (3.1.10) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
  railties (3.1.10) lib/rails/application.rb:143:in `call'
  railties (3.1.10) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  puma (2.7.1) lib/puma/rack_patch.rb:13:in `call'
  sinatra (1.3.3) lib/sinatra/base.rb:136:in `call'
  puma (2.7.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:68:in `call'
  puma (2.7.1) lib/puma/server.rb:486:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.7.1) lib/puma/server.rb:357:in `process_client'
  puma (2.7.1) lib/puma/server.rb:250:in `block in run'
  puma (2.7.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I am trying to send one file from my other python code to rails web-service.
From logs atleast I can say, control is not even reached controller action. I tried printing few log messages in controller action, those are not spitted out.

Any comments ? Where am I making mistake ?

Comment: it seems your `config/database.yml` is guilty

Comment: going to need to see more of the code involved. From the log it shows it did hit your controller action, but a "name" attribute was called on an object it wasn't expecting to be nil

Answer (score 0):

@Speransky Danil

Your comment helped me to resolve this.
'track_changes' function used to check for logged in `user`. And this POST request does not `user` to be set before. So, it was throwing an error for NilClass, as user is not set.

Thanks.